# Вопрос про std::future, обрушенный исключением поток и деструктор std::future

Tags: c++, многопоточность, исключения, future

Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию.

- Запускается фоновый поток, результат работы которого ожидается в `std::future`
- В потоке возникает исключение, которое не перехватывается и вылетает *за пределы потока*;
- Вызывается деструктор `std::future` (то есть, захваченное исключение не забирается).

Будет ли поток остановлен немедленно?
Безопасно ли уничтожать `std::future`, в котором хранится исключение?

Comment: поток не будет остановлен, он ведь результат не запросил ещё. И думаю, уничтожать можно - ничего не произойдет (исключение бросается только при вызове get)

Answer (score -1):

Поток не будет остановлен, он ведь результат не запросил ещё. Уничтожать можно - ничего не произойдет (исключение бросается только при вызове get).